# spark-submit : pass runtime variable to spark script

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-submit

I am submiting Pyspark/SparkSQL script using spark-submit option and I need to pass runtime variables (database name) to script

**spark-submit command:**

```
spark-submit --conf database_parameter=my_database my_pyspark_script.py
```

**pyspark script**

```
database_parameter = SparkContext.getConf().get("database_parameter")           

DF = sqlContext.sql("SELECT count(*) FROM database_parameter.table_name")
```

spark version is: 1.5.2
Python version is: 2.7.5

The solution I am trying is not working.  Error is : AttributeError: type object 'SparkConf' has no attribute 'getConf'.

I am looking for a way to pass runtime variable while calling the script through spark-submit and use those variables in script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the usual `sys.argv`

**args.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
print sys.argv[1]
```

Then you **`spark-submit`** it :

```
spark-submit args.py my_database
```

This will print:

```
my_database
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, there was some way to do it through --conf in spark-submit and get the value in script through getconf, but I am not able to recall that.

Comment: The parameters you pass through `--conf` should be spark related otherwise you will get `Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property`

Comment: Yeah, I am getting this warning. But there was something similar for runtime variable as well, If I can recall correctly.